# Google PubSub throw "Not found" when getting a newly created topic

Tags: node.js, async-await, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I've got a function that create topics and subscriptions when my server boots.

The problem is that I can't create subscription linked to a newly created topic, the Google PubSub server throws a NOT FOUND error.

I've even added a 20 second timeout after the topic creation but nothing changed T_T

```
export async function init() {
  // promises.topics is an array of promises
  const topics = await Promise.all(promises.topics);
  console.log('YEAH !!! TOPIC IS GOOD !', topics);
  // That works ! And it is created in my remote google PubSub
  await timeout(20000);

  console.log('Lets Check if it exists !!!');

  // promises.getTopics is an array of :
  // getTopics.push(pubSubClient.topic(topic.name).get());
  // That throws a NOT FOUND
  const get = await Promise.all(promises.getTopics);
  // Failes because Topics are not found
  const subscriptions = await Promise.all(promises.subscriptions);
}
```

When I check in the Google logs, the created topic is created AFTER the subscriptions oO

My Promise array inject first topics Then the subscriptions promises.

When adding a retry function that try again 10 times every 2 second, it don't work either.

It's no even showing in google logs, I think they have a cache ton their API that just return newly processed data without re-trying it.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks :)

TOPICS :
[image]

SUBSCRIPTION ERROR :

[image]

**EDIT :**

I Managed to fix the problem by adding a timeout('2000') after pushing the topic promise creation in my promise array.

Comment: Would you mind posting that last edit as an answer? For future reference.

Comment: In fact I will add more info about it.
I still have a unedrlying question on it ;)
Thanks for the reminder

Comment: Good to know! Let's see which question is it.

Comment: Seems that my question is interesting for google staff as well :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when I creates my Promise Array like that :

```
 async function constructPromises() {
  const topics = [];
  const subscriptions = [];
   for (const topic of pubSubConfig.topics) {      
      subscriptions.push(createTopic(topic.name));

      // Have to add this timeout, otherwise the topic is not found oO
      await timeout(1000);
   }
   for (const topic of pubSubConfig.topics) {
     for (const sub of topic.subscriptions) {        
       subscriptions.push(createSubscription(topic.name, sub));
     }       
   }
   return { topics, subscriptions };
}
```

I had to add this timeout, otherwise gcloud is not able to find the topics.

I think it's because gcloud send the resolve Promise **before** treating the request.
So when you create the subscription, he's not able to find the topic.
But I can't validate this, does anyone knows why ??!!

I wanted to remove this timeout to have a more agnostic implementation.
And even more stranger, I find that if you just call the promises in for loop, no need for timeout !

```
for (const topic of pubSubConfig.topics) {
    const topicResponse = await createTopic(topic.name);
    topics.push(topicResponse);
    for (const sub of topic.subscriptions) {
      const subResponse = await createSubscription(topic.name, sub);
      subscriptions.push(subResponse);
    }
  }
  return { topics, subscriptions };
}
```

So my problem is solved, but I still have this question in my mind :P

Comment: Hello! I'm with GCP Support, and I checked your answer. This behaviour is strange, so I suggest you to open a bug [in the Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/), posting your situation, what you have tried before, how you fixed it, etc. 

Also, if possible, could you accept your own answer when possible? For future reference of the community. You could later edit it with the results of the bug.